# Symfony data transformer typed property error

Tags: php, symfony

Getting this error when using Symfony data transformer in the form:

```
Typed property App\Entity\Gym::$workTimes must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection, App\Entity\WorkTime used
```

This happens when I do this in the form:

```
$builder->add('title', TextType::class);
$builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
```

It **works** if I add transformer straight on to the field like this:

```
$builder->add(
$builder->create('title', TextType::class)
->addModelTransformer($transformer)
);
```

I need to make it work the first way cause there are more than one field. This is the transformer:

```
public function reverseTransform($value)
{
   $newWorktime = new WorkTime();
   $newWorktime->setTitle($value['title']);
   $newWorktime->setTime('18:00');

   return $newWorktime;
}
```

Comment: Try return new ArrayCollection([$newWorktime]) in transformer. Your Entity need a list of WorkTimes instead of a single WorkTime

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure to understand what you're asking for.
So i'll try to anwser hoping this is what you were looking for.

You can build multiple field and only have some of them use a transformer.

```php
private $transformer;

public function __construct(YourTransformer $transformer)
{
   $this->transformer = $transformer;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
    ->add('Title', TextType::class)
    ->add(
         $builder->create('someOtherField', TextType::class)
                    ->addModelTransformer($this->transformer));
    
}
```

Hoping this is what you were looking for.